# Python Django and DecimalField

Tags: python, django, math, django-rest-framework, decimal

In my MySQL database I have such values:

```
+-------+----------------------------------+----------------------+
| id    | balance                          | max(length(balance)) |
+-------+----------------------------------+----------------------+
| 39081 |           1.1102230246251565e-16 |                   22 |
| 41565 |  0.00000000000002930988785010413 |                   31 |
| 37692 |   0.0000000000000315303338993544 |                   30 |
| 39409 |  0.00000000000004263256414560601 |                   31 |
| 37498 |    0.000000000000049737991503207 |                   29 |
| 39943 | 0.000000000000050912399296443305 |                   32 |
| 35856 |    0.000000000000116351372980716 |                   29 |
| 41163 |   0.0000000000004618527782440651 |                   30 |
| 44612 |   0.0000000000006898925875020723 |                   30 |
| 40211 |   0.0000000000009268141809570807 |                   30 |
+-------+----------------------------------+----------------------+
```

'balance' column type is 'double'.

If I use FloatFiled in my model or in django rest framework serializers I get original values from table. For money recommend using DecimalField (Python's Decimal)

For example:

```
balance = serializers.DecimalField(decimal_places=35, max_digits=40, default=0)
```

And 1.1102230246251565e-16 from MySQL table is becoming 0.00000000000000011102230246251565000.
Not bad, but if balance value from table = 263.74645817644887 I will have 263.74645817644887000000000000000000000 after processing etc. And if balance = 0 I will have 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000.

In mathematics of course 263.74645817644887 and 263.74645817644887000000000000000000000 are the same as well as 0 equal 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000.

And what to do if value has more than 35 digits after decimal point?

But I want to ask question: I'm doing everything right in this case with such values? My doubts are that if third-party script in PHP or Perl will do addition/subtraction etc. operations with my new values (Python's Decimal) can there be problems with precision?

**Or use FloatField with fixed precision? Because if before data was inserted as Float (in Perl or PHP, not Python) it is better to continue using FLOAT?. But I couldn't find how to set precision to FloadField in Django or Django Rest Framework serializers**

In pure Python I can do:

```
>>> f'{1.1102230246251565e-16:.35f}'
'0.00000000000000011102230246251565404'
```

How do that in Django or DRF?

If I use FloatField I get **5.0912399296443305e-14** instead **0.000000000000050912399296443305** as in table.

P.S. notice there is already a difference in the values (Decimal and Float):

```
0.00000000000000011102230246251565000
0.00000000000000011102230246251565404
```

Comment: TLDR, Can you brief what is your requirement?

Comment: @JPG minimum: Solve that: If I use FloatField I get 5.0912399296443305e-14 instead 0.000000000000050912399296443305 as in table. If i use DecimalField i can format this value, but if FloatField() - No.

Comment: table? Database table? or DRF response?

Comment: @JPG maximum: Get ideal solution to store values as Decimal with large decimal places without loss in accuracy

Comment: @JPG 0.000000000000050912399296443305  stored in database table, 5.0912399296443305e-14 in DRF response if I use FloatField